# How to reset animation of dougtesting.net?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I am using library dougtesting.net to create a wheel. I tried to find a way to reset animation when a animation has finised but can't find any info. I expect to clear every state so that the wheel back to original posittion, (like we have not executed function startAnimation()). Could you please suggest an idea?

```
let luckyDrawWheel = new Winwheel({
      canvasId: "lucky-draw-canvas",
      drawText: true,
      numSegments: 8,
      textAlignment: "inner",
      textFontSize: 10,
      textMargin: 35,
      textFontFamily: "TUV Poetsen One",
      imageOverlay: true,
      segments: [...],
      animation: {
        type: "spinToStop",
        duration: 5,
        spins: 8,
        callbackFinished: alertPrize,
      },
    });
    // Called when the animation as finished.
    function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
    {
        alert(indicatedSegment.text + ' says Hi');
    }
    luckyDrawWheel.draw();

    const runWheelBtn = document.getElementById("run_wheel");
    runWheelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      luckyDrawWheel.startAnimation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `luckyDrawWheel.rotationAngle = 0;` and `luckyDrawWheel.draw();`

You code should then look like

```
let luckyDrawWheel = new Winwheel({
  canvasId: "lucky-draw-canvas",
  drawText: true,
  numSegments: 8,
  textAlignment: "inner",
  textFontSize: 10,
  textMargin: 35,
  textFontFamily: "TUV Poetsen One",
  imageOverlay: true,
  segments: [...],
  animation: {
    type: "spinToStop",
    duration: 5,
    spins: 8,
    callbackFinished: alertPrize,
  },
});
// Called when the animation as finished.
function alertPrize(indicatedSegment) {
  alert(indicatedSegment.text + ' says Hi');
  luckyDrawWheel.rotationAngle = 0;
  luckyDrawWheel.draw();
}
luckyDrawWheel.draw();

const runWheelBtn = document.getElementById("run_wheel");
runWheelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  luckyDrawWheel.startAnimation();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much it works perfect. Also, I am trying to add image to segments number 3. But with this case, this library require to add images for all other segment. Once image added, the fillStyle property will not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @vanminhquangtri I'm not sure that is possible after looking at the js code inside the Winwheel.js.